# Python line endings syntax error with end=''

Tags: python

I started learning python the other day. I have a fibonacci function that I copied from python docs. It gives a syntax error on the print statement with the end=''

I rewrote all the code manually and still i get the error

```
def fibonacci2(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        print(b, end=' ')
        a, b = b, a+b
    print()
```

It says `syntax error while detecting tuple`

Thanks in advance

edit: i am sorry that i forgot to write, i am  using python 3.

Comment: Put `from __future__ import print_function` atop the file (or upgrade to Python 3).

Answer (score 1):

In `Python 3.x` you can write `print(b, end=' ')`, you cant write `print(b, end=' ')` in `Python 2.x` . Because in `Python 3.x` `print` is function and in `Python 2.x` `print` is just statement.

If you want to use `end=''` in print statement in `Python 2.x` you should use `from __future__ import print_function`

Answer (score 0):

it's important to remember that in python < V3.x `print` is not a function